# how to get field page in PDFBox API 2?

Tags: java, pdfbox

i'm trying to get the field page in my project,
and i dont know how to get the page number for each field and field.
i have this code:

```
    String formTemplate = "Template.pdf";
    String filledForm = "filledForm.pdf";
    PDDocument pdfDocument = PDDocument.load(new File(formTemplate));

    PDAcroForm acroForm = pdfDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();

    if (acroForm != null)
    {

        PDField field = acroForm.getField( "name" );
        field.getAcroForm().setNeedAppearances(true);
        field.setValue("my name");
        acroForm.getField( "date" );
        field.setValue("my date");


    }

    pdfDocument.save(filledForm);
    pdfDocument.close();
}
```

How do I get the page numbers of the fields?

thanks
ron

Comment: the line with "date" is missing the assignment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will show you on what page(s) (0-based) the field appears:

```
PDField field = acroForm.getField( "date" );
for (PDAnnotationWidget widget : field.getWidgets())
{
    PDPage page = widget.getPage();
    if (page == null)
    {
        // incorrect PDF. Plan B: try all pages to check the annotations.
        for (int p = 0; p < doc.getNumberOfPages(); ++p)
        {
            List<PDAnnotation> annotations = doc.getPage(p).getAnnotations();
            for (PDAnnotation ann : annotations)
            {
                if (ann.getCOSObject() == widget.getCOSObject())
                {
                    System.out.println("found at page: " + p);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        continue;
    }
    int pageNum = pdfDocument.getPages().indexOf(page);
    System.out.println("found at page: " + pageNum);
}
```

Comment: its dont work..                                                                             Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageTree$SearchContext.<init>(PDPageTree.java:355)
 at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageTree$SearchContext.<init>(PDPageTree.java:347)
 at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageTree.indexOf(PDPageTree.java:319)
 at Main.main(Main.java:85)

Comment: @RonPartuk I implemented a "Plan B" for the case that getPage() returns null.

Comment: Theoretically form fields may also be associated with named page templates which are not yet part of the page tree. Such page templates seldom are used nowadays but every once in a while one may come across such an animal...

Comment: And another problem, some fields simply are not connected to any page, not even a template. In particular invisible signatures do not have to be associated to any page. Thus, you had better harden the code against both `page` objects not in the page tree and null `page` objects.