# pdfBox Find page no that contains signature field

Tags: java, pdfbox

If I have a 2 page pdf document with a signature field (signature1), how can I parse the document using pdfBox to find which page contains the signature field (either blank or signed).
OR how can I find the page No for signature1 in a multi page pdf document?

I can successfully add a signature field to page 2:

```java
page = doc.getPage(1)

widget = signatureField.getWidgets().get(0)

widget.setAppearance(appearanceDictionary)

widget.setRectangle(rect)

//set it to page 2

widget.setPage(page)
```

from code example:
https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDSignatureField

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get page index of pdf page containing digital signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51530482/get-page-index-of-pdf-page-containing-digital-signature)

Comment: have answered this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22074449/how-to-know-if-a-field-is-on-a-particular-page

Answer (score 1):

assuming you have the widget and it is not null:

```
PDPage signaturePage = widget.getPage();
int pageIndex = document.getPages().indexOf(signaturePage);
```

now you have the 0-based page number.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the widget **P** page property is optional as far as the pdf specification is concerned. So if **P** is not present, does `widget.getPage()` meanwhile search the page? Or does it simply return `null`?

Comment: See also your [older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36894982/1729265) I closed this as a duplicate of

Comment: Yeah, the older answer is really better. No, getPage() doesn't search, and it returns null.